# css how to specify a styling for a nest element?

Tags: html, css

the li a:hover is not working.
Nothing is changing when i hover it.
the color should change but is nothing

```
li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
```

}

```
<nav>
<ul id=naw>
    <li><!--<a> should be here-->home</li>
    <li><!--<a> should be here-->stock</li>
    <li><!--<a> should be here-->about me</li>
    <li><!--<a> should be here-->braclets tutorial</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you haven't added a tag in html

Comment: Do you realize that you have anchor tag `a` commented out and you expect for  `hover` to work?

Comment: the anwser is within your code .. so simply read the code ...

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
li a:hover {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id=naw>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stock</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">braclets tutorial</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note : If you have other css rules, for override it use `!important` like this:

```
li a:hover {
 background-color: #555!important;
 color: white!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<ul id="naw">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stock</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">braclets tutorial</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS,

```
#naw li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without `a` tag** (do not forget to add `""` to `id` of `ul`)

```css
li:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul id="naw">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>stock</li>
    <li>about me</li>
    <li>braclets tutorial</li>
</ul>
```

**With `a` tag:**

```css
    li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul id="naw">
        <li><a> should be here</a>home</li>
        <li><a> should be here</a>stock</li>
        <li><a> should be here</a>about me</li>
        <li><a> should be here</a>braclets tutorial</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<ul id="naw">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">stock</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">braclets tutorial</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
#naw li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
   color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xz7fueo1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working

```css
ul li a:hover{
color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul id=naw>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stock</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">braclets tutorial</a></li>
</ul>
```